# if/else statement not being executed in UITextView delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a if/else statement in my objective-c code.  The if/else statement runs like this:

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(textView==self.heardTextView)
    {
        NSString *string = textView.text;
        if ([string rangeOfString:@"CLOSER"].location == NSNotFound)    
        {
           NSLog(@"closest");
        } 
    }
}
```

The premise of the if/else statement is - if the `textview` equals a certain word some code will run.  But this code isn't running.

I have put a `breakpoint` on my code and a `NSLOG` and nothing.

Comment: Do you mean the whole method doesn't execute or what's inside the if statement doesn't execute?  Have you set your object as the text view's delegate?

Comment: the whole method doesn't execute

Comment: what do you mean by, setting object as a text view's delegate?

Comment: He means that the code you provided probably belongs to a `UIViewController` subclass. So, did you a) Ctrl-drag from your `UITextView` to your view controller and make the `delegate` connection, b)  do it in code instead, or c) forget to do this?

Comment: you got your anaswer

Comment: Does your delegate method call first once you put the break point?

Answer (score 0):

check your text field  delegate if you not set your delegate then it's not called..

In your Viewcontroller.H

[image]

select your textview give delegate on textview.

[image]

Comment: i have implemented everything you said.  But still isn't running

Comment: give me your skype id

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set the delegate of the text view. You can do this with Interface Builder, but if you prefer using code you can do this in the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller:

```
myTextView.delegate = self;
```

Now, when do you want the `NSLog` statement to be executed? Right now it looks like it will be run only if you type "CLOSER", then make the text view lose focus and then click on it again.

If you want the `NSLog` to run as you type, you should use:

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

And also be careful, you need to calculate the next string value in the text field before testing its contents:

```
NSString *finalText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your delegates, you must not have made the delegate of your textview as self. Check it once again. Or you might have done to some other class.